# Authentication error using Yahoo Finance in Power BI when updating data

Tags: powerbi

When trying to autoupdate stock values using Yahoo Finance link from a csv file using this:

```
Source = Csv.Document(
    Web.Contents(
      "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/"
        & Comp
        & "?period1=1022112000&period2="
        & LastDate
        & "&interval=1d&events=history"
    ), 
    [Delimiter = ",", Columns = 7, Encoding = 1252, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.None]
```

Extra info:  Comp and lastdate are custom parameters, in which comp fetches all company stock data and lastdate records the most recent stock date.

I keep getting authentication errors everytime I try to access the data using either anonymous or user login. What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check what value you provide to the URL string. Probably there is some error.

You can check this example with function:

```
let
    Source = (STOCKNAME, StartDat, EndDat) => let
            Source = Csv.Document(Web.Contents("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/"&STOCKNAME&"?period1="&StartDat&"&period2="&EndDat&"&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
            #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
            #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Date", type date}, {"Open", type text}, {"High", type text}, {"Low", type text}, {"Close", type text}, {"Adj Close", type text}, {"Volume", Int64.Type}})
        in
            #"Changed Type"
in
    Source
```

Query:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WCgkPCVLSUTI0M7E0MzY1MjCAcsyNDM2AnFidaCVPvxBnVFEIx8LAwgCkJBYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [TICKER = _t, Start = _t, End = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TICKER", type text}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "GetStock", each GetStock([TICKER], [Start], [End])),
    #"Expanded GetStock" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "GetStock", {"Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Adj Close", "Volume"}, {"GetStock.Date", "GetStock.Open", "GetStock.High", "GetStock.Low", "GetStock.Close", "GetStock.Adj Close", "GetStock.Volume"})
in
    #"Expanded GetStock"
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Solved it and now it's running just like I wanted it to.